# how to know how many times button has been clicked?

Tags: delphi, button

I want to do something after the button is clicked the 2nd time and the 3rd time and so on.

Comment: Have you tried declaring an attribute on the form?

Comment: no idk how, i tried `Button2.Tag := StrToInt(Label1.Text);` but useless @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: If you must abuse the `Tag` property to track click counts `Button2.Tag:= Button2.Tag + 1` will do the trick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Declare a form-level variable, and increment it each time the button is clicked.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    // component/control variables
  private
    FClickCount: Integer;
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FClickCount := FClickCount + 1;  // or Inc(FClickCount);
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but, FWIW, this is how I would do it.

If the button clicked count does not need to be used outside of the OnClick() handler, you could keep the counter local to the handler by using a typed constant like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1.click(Sender: TObject);
{$J+}
const
  counter: integer = 0;
{$J-}
begin
  inc(counter);

  if (counter < 2) then exit;
end;
```

Notes:

1)  the {$J+} allows assignment to typed constants.

2)  the use of typed constants like this has been deprecated for many years (even though they are useful for stuff like this - keeping the declaration and use of a "variable" close to each other is a good thing in my book and using a form level variable for this seems wrong as it kind of breaks encapsulation).

Comment: Ugh. Writable constants are ugly. When you write `const`, it should mean *const*, not *kludgy use of a value declared as constant as a variable instead*. Writable constants belong in the same category as goto. *Deprecated for years* means *don't tell people they can use them*, and especially *don't teach new developers to start off by using deprecated means*.

Comment: Beauty (ugliness) is in the eye of the beholder.  I'm of the opinion that a form variable in this context is ugly.  Using the tag property for this may be a good compromise, but that has been described as "abuse" in another comment. My order of preference would be the use of a typed const followed by using the tag property followed by using a form variable.  With the idea of encapsulation being held high.

Comment: No. *Deprecated functionality* being added to new code is ugly no matter who beholds it. It's the equivalent of telling someone to start a new database application using the BDE and Paradox. If you're *that* insistent on ridiculous unnecessary scope reduction, a better solution than yours would be to move the button click event to the end of the unit and declare a global counter just above the procedure; it narrows the scope just as well because it's only visible from the point of its declaration on, it allows initialization, and doesn't confuse the code by *writing to constants*.

Comment: LOL - its a whole different scale to saying use the BDE and Paradox.  And, if ever the guys at embarcadero decide to remove the feature - which I don't think will ever happen - its a simple fix to replace it with an ugly-ass form level variable.  I'm not that insistent.  I said I held encapsulation high, not necessarily highest and not essential.  Encapsulation ideas are important are they not!?  Whilst your suggested to move it to the end of the unit would work, I wouldn't use it.  Typed constants do a much better job, even if variable constants are an oxymoron. I smile every time I use one.